# Querying mongodb for a range of days

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I have a MongoDB database with data in the form of {"year":2016, "day":364} and this database has a wide range of year. For a range of days, for example, if I need documents from the year 2016, days 307 to 350, I used

```
Flux.find({year:{$gte:2016, $lt: 2016+1}, day: {$gte:307, $lt: 350}})
```

which worked fine. But If I need documents from the year 2016 day 350 to the year 2017 day 25,

```
Flux.find({year:{$gte:2016, $lt: 2017+1}, day: {$gte:350, $lt: 25}})
```

returned 0 documents. Please let me know what would be a good way to approach this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer below is correct but just a simple modification,

```
Flux.find({
    $or : [
        { year: 2016, day: {$gte: 350} },
        { year: 2017, day: {$lte: 25 } }
    ]
})
```

Basically, you are looking for "$or" operator. Problem with your query is that the records such as { year: 2016, day: 13 } and { year: 2017, day: 364 } will also pass.

Answer (score 0):

This query, even if it works will also return data from days 0-25 of year 2016, which isn't correct.
Use MongoDB's [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to achieve the right query. Something like this:

```
dbFlux.find({
  $or: [
      { year:{ $gte: 2016, $lt: 2016+1 }, day: { $gte: 350 } }),
      { year:{ $gte: 2017, $lt: 2017+1 }, day: { $lt: 25 } })
  ]
})
```